# Heroku not compiling images in a sub folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets, precompile

Just deployed my app to heroku and had the "Something went wrong" page appear (500 Internal Server Error).

After checking the logs I can see the error comes from this

```
ActionView::Template::Error (./slider/new_york_2.jpg isn't precompiled):
```

Within assets/images i have another folder called slider which is for all my images that are in the slider ( trying to keep things organised).

In my view i then display the image like so

```
<%= image_tag('./slider/new_york_2.jpg') %>
```

This works in development but not in production it seems.. Am i making a silly mistake anywhere or does heroku specifically not see images in sub fodlers? Im guessing it has something to do with the path structure though?

Any help appreciated

Comment: did you precompile your assets? before pushing them to heroku.

Comment: well it does that whilst deploying to heroku, also when i put the image in just asssets/images it all works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several possibilities here:

---

**Path**

You're using a relative path

You say it's in a view - view paths are based on the `assets/images` folder. So it *can't* be relative, as it already is. I would recommend removing the relative path, and basing it on the `assets/images` folder structure, like this:

```
<%= image_tag('slider/new_york_2.jpg') %>
```

---

**Precompile**

If you're using Heroku, [you have to precompile your assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

This keeps consistency & is quite simple to do:

```
#config/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then when you deploy to Heroku, you should do this:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This should help!

Comment: I didn't know that view paths where only based on assets/images, so thanks for that... I've put everything in assets/images and stopped using relative paths, all fine

Comment: Although they're based on the `assets/images` structure, the `precompile` process actually puts all the assets in the `app/public` folder :) The `image_path` helper directs the paths accordingly!

Comment: thanks. slightly off subject but there seems to be an issue with your site when you click the products link... 502 error

Comment: Hey thanks man - we've got a new site coming out very soon with updated stuff on there!!

Comment: Cardiff, South Wales...Not too far away :)

Comment: Nice! You a full time dev?

Comment: im launching a blog soon so looking to get some followers on twitter and maybe get some others from Cardiff involved in some projects :)

Comment: Good!! You need to get involved with the local business community as much as possible. Get yourself a [`CRM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) and you'll start attracting projects. If you're good, people will refer you on, which will grow substantially over time. The trick is to appreciate the *people* (not the project). This means look at what the people desire, and work to those standards